# I can't find ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework). ".NET Framework project and item templates" and this component was selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2022

[I choose net framework project and item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzAf6.png)

[can't find ASP.NET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwMIG.png)

I can't find ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework).

Inside the .NET group, below the ".NET Framework 4.8 targeting pack", there is a component named ".NET Framework project and item templates" and this component was selected.

But there was no ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) template.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a few more workflows and templates.

So, from VS, tools->Get Tools and Features.

Make sure you selected these:

[image]

The "class designer" of course does not matter, but it is nice to have. Same goes for the RDLC Report Designer if you used the web-based report builder in the past.

And in the above list, I recommend all of the Optional choices I have in above.

Once done, then you find the traditional WebForms "web site" option (I recommend you don't use such projects), and you find the WebForms web site Application which is of course the recommended type of project to choose when building web forms applications.

Thus choose 1 of theses (vb.net, or c#).

[image]